# How print PDF document with user setting?

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I am trying to print a pdf document using **java.awt.print.PrinterJob.print (PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes)**. Before that, I put the necessary attributes in attributes using **PrinterJob.printerDialog (attributes)** and they really get there, but from everything I've tried, only the change in the number of pages that will be printed has been applied. The rest of the settings are ignored. How can I get the printer to print with the settings I want?

pdfReport - byte[] which was obtained with DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary from
printerService - standart "Microsoft Print to PDF"

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfReport);
try {
  PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  job.setPrintService(printer.printerService);
  HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
  if (job.printDialog(attributes)) {
    try {
      job.print(attributes);
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

} finally {
  document.close();
}
```

P.S. : when the program is running, **sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob** is used as the PrinterJob implemenjatation

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide us with what you have tried. Post your code and tell us your input and what you output you want.

Comment: Please include an [MCVE].

Comment: I added code to my question